# Android live server connection status

Tags: android, connection, monitoring

Wondering if its possible to monitor constantly some wifi connection to a server (some ip and port) and display the status of the connection, that is if the server is accessible/responsive or not.

By displaying the status i mean updating some textview displaying either "server up" or "server down".
(something similar to the wifi icon next to the battery indication at the top right..)

Comment: Yes, it is.....

Comment: @ blackapps - haha. any clues how? ConnectivityManager maybe? where to start?

Comment: Try to connect to that server.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is to make a thread class, which will constantly call (with a while loop) an asynctask. The asynctask will (try to) connect to the mysql server. the connection will be successful or not and accordingly a `textview` or something will be updated in the `UIthread` (using `runOnUiThread`)

an example of the code for the thread:

```
class servlookthread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (keeplookingserver){
            lookforserver lserv = new lookforserver(); // this is the asynctask thread
            try {lserv.execute().get();} catch (ExecutionException e) {e.printStackTrace();} catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();} //! .get() it waits until the asynctask finishes
            try {Thread.sleep(4000);} catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();} // some delay, 4 seconds
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

the keeplookingserver is a boolean, "global" variable used to control the execution of the thread.

hope this helps someone! although i think its not elegant, its working for me